# Put nav and img elements inline and above a common border

Tags: css

I am trying to put `nav` and `img` elements next to each other on top of the page.

I am putting both elements in the `top_bar` container.

I have tried setting the `top_bar` to `display: inline-block;`, reducing the width of `nav` and floating it to left and also floating the `img` to right. Then I have tried combinations of those, but nothing gives me the result I want. Either the elements start to jump around or the logo is put below the `top_bar` border.

How can I have `nav` and `img` inline and both above the `top_bar` bottom border?

**EDIT**: I also want the `nav` element to be positioned left-most of the page, and `img` right-most.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
  <head>
   <style>
    #top_bar {
     border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
    }
    nav ul li {
     display: inline-block;
    }
    img {
     width: 130px;
     height: 30px;
    }
   </style>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div id="top_bar">
    <nav>
     <ul>
      <li>Link 1</li>
      <li>Link 2</li>
      <li>Link 3</li>
     </ul>
    </nav>
    <img src="cs_logo.png" alt="Image not found"></img>
   </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display: flex;` to `#top_bar`

```css
#top_bar {
  border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
img {
  width: 130px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="top_bar">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>Link 1</li>
      <li>Link 2</li>
      <li>Link 3</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <img src="cs_logo.png" alt="Image not found"></img>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, it might not have been clear from my question that I need to put `nav` to the left and `img` to the right. Can you code be amended to achieve that?

Comment: @barciewicz Add `justify-content: space-between;` - Answer edited

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
  <head>
   <style>
    #top_bar {
     border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
                    display: flex;
                    flex-direction: row;
                    align-items: center;
    }
    nav ul li {
     display: inline-block;
    }
               
    img {
     width: 130px;
     height: 30px;
    }
   </style>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div id="top_bar">
    <nav>
     <ul>
      <li>Link 1</li>
      <li>Link 2</li>
      <li>Link 3</li>
     </ul>
    </nav>
    <img src="cs_logo.png" alt="Image not found"></img>
   </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

We can use CSS flex properties to achieve this. But please make sure that you are using vendor prefixes for cross browser compatability.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is missing some declarations.

At first your class #top_bar should have a width declaration.
To make things easyier you could use a class instead of only declare 
the image size.

Here´s a fiddle of your code that i´ve modified: https://jsfiddle.net/Thorske/nyv6mwgz/

Modified css:

```
       * {
             margin : 0:
             padding : 0;
            }
            #top_bar {
             margin : 0 auto;
             width : 100%;
            border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
            }
            .clear {
             clear : both;
            }
            nav { 
            float : left;
            width : 80%;
            }
            nav ul li {
                display: inline-block;
            }
            .img_container {
            float : right;
            width : 20%;
            }
            .img_conatiner img {
                width: 130px;
                height: 30px;
            }
```

Modifed html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <head>

        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="top_bar">
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Link 1</li>
                        <li>Link 2</li>
                        <li>Link 3</li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
 <div class="img_container">
                <img src="cs_logo.png" alt="Image not found" />
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

There only simple changes:

- the #top_bar has now a defined width.
- nav has now a defined width and float.
- added the class "img_container" with defindet width and float
  which contains the image.
- the class clear keeps everything were it is supposed to be.

Since i don´t know if you want to make your code "responsiv" you´ve 
to set your values for "width" yourself.